# Mail Compose not dismiss when click cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have this code who send a e-mail to users, Im using MFMailCompose:

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> mailComposeDelegate;
```

**.m file**

```
@synthesize mailComposeDelegate

-(void)sendEmail:(NSString*)valor{

//Valor receive the email

    NSString *corpoMensagem = @"No have body yet...";

    // From within your active view controller
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;// Required to invoke mailComposeController when send

        [mailCont setSubject:@"FazerBem - Recibo de Compra"];
        [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:valor]];
        [mailCont setMessageBody:corpoMensagem isHTML:YES];

        [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    if (error){
        NSString *errorTitle = @"Erro to send";
        NSString *errorDescription = [error localizedDescription];
        UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:errorTitle message:errorDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [errorView show];
    }

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{


}
```

when I click the send button he can send the email to the recipient and can close the screen, now when I click the cancel button, it opens 2 more options 'delete draft' and 'save draft' when I click on one of the app crashes and returns me the following error:

```
[TestViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16b3b470
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Also, turn on exception breakpoints to figure out what line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Switch case to for performing actions:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert;
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Draft Saved" message:@"Composed Mail is saved in draft." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"You have successfully referred your friends." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Sorry! Failed to send." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// Close the Mail Interface
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: The message when I send a e-mail works, but when I click in save draft or delete draft that error occurred again  and the alert don't show...

Comment: remove from header, this might help
    #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
    @property(nonatomic,assign) id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> mailComposeDelegate;

Comment: are you sending email to single person or multiple peoples?

Comment: did not have to delete the lines, but actually I do not know what exactly happened now, but your code started to work perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: Welcome. If you want i can update my code so that you can modify and use it.

Comment: Oh I know what is happened, I create the following code, When I shell some itens in my app and send the e-mail for the clients the app return to main view (with no have the email codes), but Why sometimes get error on send and why sometimes not get this error? But I do it fast (I click on the buttons exists inside the email view after the screen go back to main view)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:
`[self becomeFirstResponder];`

That should fix your problem.

Comment: No, If I remove that line the e-mail don't send and the the mail not dissmiss

Comment: @user3781174 what is your view controller hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

If above solution didn't work for you as it was for me, here, instead  of **self** use **instance of MFMailComposeViewController**:

Instead Of

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Use

```
[mailComposer dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```